# How to get a single line per string in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I am currently playing with javascript and trying to get the hang of it. I was wondering how to get each greeting in one line rather than one after the other after the other. Hope my question makes sense.

```
window.onload = function() {
getGreeting();
};

for(var hours=0; hours < 24; hours++)
{

document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML + "\n" +  getGreeting(hours); 
}


function getGreeting(hours) {
    var greetingText;
    if (hours >=6 && hours < 12) {
        greetingText = "Good morning!";
    } else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 17) {
        greetingText = "Good afternoon!";
    } else if (hours >= 17 && hours < 23) {
        greetingText = "Good Evening!";
    } else if (hours >= 23 || hours < 6) {
        greetingText = "Go to sleep!";
    }
    return greetingText;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/KcS5b/   you see in the jsfiddle file that the greetings are lined up one after the other, I would like to know how to get one per line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the `\n` with `<br />`

http://jsfiddle.net/KcS5b/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using the newline character `\n` where you'd like a new line to be added. In HTML, whitespace is not regarded as relevant markup. This makes sense, when you think about it. You'd want to write HTML with tabs and newlines, but not have those spaces appear in the resulting document.

The semantic markup you're looking for is the line break tag, `br`.

Edit: Additionally, you could wrap each greeting in a block-level element, such as a `div`. By default, a series of `div`s will stack vertically. This has the benefit of compartmentalizing each greeting in its own semantic markup, allowing you to apply unique styles, target individually with JavaScript, etc. Obviously for your simple example, it may be overkill but this extends to general web development principles.

Comment: Or preferably <br /> since it's compatible with both xhtml and html5

Comment: @apelsinapa you're right that it's more compatible, but the question didn't specify so I omitted it intentionally to make a subtle statement about adopting newer standards :)

Comment: No need to defend yourself, I just wanted the inquirer to get the best possible answer =)

Comment: I'll rewrite it to reference the name of the tag, since the markup implementation is less relevant to the question and should make everyone happy. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML+=getGreeting(hours);
```

Use concatenation (+) as shown above!